# Pass value outside of public void onClick

Tags: android, class, onclick, integer

So im sure this is probably a fairly easy question but I am stumped because I am a beginner.

I am looking to pass a value from one class to another, and I have my helper function down and working just fine.  If i create an integer outside of my onClick I can pass it no problem.  If I create it inside the onClick though it doesn't seem to make it out.

```
package com.movi.easypar;

//import java.util.logging.Handler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class EntryScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonSetHoles, buttonSetPlayers, buttonLetsGo;
TextView textGameSetup;
public int setHoles; <--- declared here###############################
private String name1 = "Crista";
private String name2 = "Rob";
private String name3 = "Gato";
private String name4 = "Movi";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen);


    //******************//
    //***DEFINE FONTS***//
    //******************//
    Typeface merge = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "merge.otf");

    //*****************************************************//
    //***CREATES THE UI FOR EACH OF THESE IN JAVA MEMORY***//
    //*****************************************************//
    buttonSetHoles = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetHoles);
    buttonSetPlayers = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetPlayers);
    buttonLetsGo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLetsGo);
    textGameSetup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textGameSetup);
    buttonSetHoles.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonSetPlayers.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonLetsGo.setTypeface(merge);
    textGameSetup.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonSetHoles.setText("Set Holes");
    buttonLetsGo.setText("Lets Go");
    buttonSetPlayers.setText("Set Players");

    //******************************//
    //***DEFINES BUTTON LISTENERS***//
    //******************************//
    buttonSetHoles.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSetPlayers.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonLetsGo.setOnClickListener(this);
}






//*************************************************//
//***SETS ON CLICK FUNCTIONALITY FOR ALL BUTTONS***//
//*************************************************//
@Override
public void onClick(View src) {

    switch(src.getId()){

    case R.id.buttonSetPlayers:
        break;

    case R.id.buttonSetHoles:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final CharSequence[] items = {"18", "9"};
        builder.setTitle("Set Holes");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (items[item].equals("9")){
                    EntryScreen.this.setHoles = 9; <---#### VALUE SET HERE ####

                }
                else if (items[item].equals("18")){
                    EntryScreen.this.setHoles = 18;

                }

                return;
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();

        return;

    case R.id.buttonLetsGo:
        //*********************************//
        //***LAUNCHES ACTUAL APPLICATION***//
        //*********************************//
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, -500, 0,0 );
        slide.setDuration(1000);   
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        buttonLetsGo.startAnimation(slide);
        buttonSetPlayers.startAnimation(slide);
        buttonSetHoles.startAnimation(slide);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(src.getContext(), EasyPar.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        break;
    }
    EntryScreen.this.finish();
}   


public String getNames() {
    return name1;
}

public void setNames(String playerName1) {
    name1 = playerName1;
}

public int getHoles() {
    return setHoles;  <---- #### THIS DOES NOT SEE VALUE SET IN ONCLICK ####
}
}
```

This helper does not seem to be able to see the setHoles value that is created onClick.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what exactly do you need to pass, and to where?

Comment: I am wanting the setHoles value in Helper, to be recognize and be the same value from setHoles in the onClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope thing. A variable defined in a function has local scope, and will be destroyed when the function returns. You need a field to hold your value if you wish to retain it.

[EDIT]
Then allow me to elaborate. You can create a field by typing the following line outside a function, inside the class:

[Access][Type][Name];

ex:

```
class foo{
    public int dice;
    public void onClick(){
         //now the dice's value is saved throught the lifecycle of the Activity
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
I copied your code and ran it. (Modified just a little.)

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonSetHoles, buttonSetPlayers, buttonLetsGo;
TextView textGameSetup;
public int setHoles; //<--- declared here###############################
private String name1 = "Crista";
private String name2 = "Rob";
private String name3 = "Gato";
private String name4 = "Movi";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //******************//
    //***DEFINE FONTS***//
    //******************//
    Typeface merge = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "merge.otf");

    //*****************************************************//
    //***CREATES THE UI FOR EACH OF THESE IN JAVA MEMORY***//
    //*****************************************************//
    /*

    buttonSetPlayers = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSetPlayers);
    buttonLetsGo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLetsGo);
    textGameSetup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textGameSetup);
    */
    buttonSetHoles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetHoles);
    /*
    buttonSetHoles.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonSetPlayers.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonLetsGo.setTypeface(merge);
    textGameSetup.setTypeface(merge);
    buttonSetHoles.setText("Set Holes");
    buttonLetsGo.setText("Lets Go");
    buttonSetPlayers.setText("Set Players");
    */

    //******************************//
    //***DEFINES BUTTON LISTENERS***//
    //******************************//.
    buttonSetHoles.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*
    buttonSetPlayers.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonLetsGo.setOnClickListener(this);
    */
}

//*************************************************//
//***SETS ON CLICK FUNCTIONALITY FOR ALL BUTTONS***//
//*************************************************//
@Override
public void onClick(View src) {

    switch (src.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonSetHoles:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final CharSequence[] items = { "18", "9" };
            builder.setTitle("Set Holes");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (items[item].equals("9")) {
                        setHoles = 9;// <---#### VALUE SET HERE ####
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "getHoles()=" + getHoles(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    else if (items[item].equals("18")) {
                        setHoles = 18;
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "getHoles()=" + getHoles(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                    return;
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();

            return;

    }
    //finish();
}

public String getNames() {
    return name1;
}

public void setNames(String playerName1) {
    name1 = playerName1;
}

public int getHoles() {
    return setHoles;
}
}
```

And it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I think you are on to something, Just need to figure out how to create that field to hold the value.  I thought thats what I was doing by declaring int setHoles at the beginning but no dice.

Comment: I have this at the beginning: public class EntryScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 
 Button buttonSetHoles, buttonSetPlayers, buttonLetsGo;
 TextView textGameSetup;
  --------- >>>> public int setHoles;

Comment: see the update I posted?  I have public int setHoles; up there, however its not triggering it.. private String name1 = "Crista"; carries over just fine... if i change int setHoles; to int setHoles = 18; then it works, but I need to have that determined based on user clicking

Comment: so public int getHoles() {
     return setHoles;
    } returns 9 or 18?

Comment: Could the problem be in my main activity where I am trying to use the value.. I run this in onCreate, int setHoles = EasyPar.helper.getHoles(); to get the value and set, setHoles

Comment: Yes. That would be a scope problem.

Comment: But at the very bottom public int getHoles() {
    return setHoles;
}... i dont think that "return setHoles" is = 18 or 9

Comment: So how can i get setHoles outside of that scope?

Comment: If you're passing data to another Activity, you must use intents and bundles. Google "intent putExtra" for more info regarding that.

Comment: Sheldon, could we chat in the Android chat room real quick?

Comment: It is, you're just not calling it correctly. I'm guessing that you 2 activities A & B, A decides the value of setHole, and B wants to read the value of setHole, so you call A.helper.getHole. Problem is, you can't do it this way. You must use intents and bundles to pass data between activities.

Comment: You could also make setHoles static if you want to pass data through intents.

Comment: I can't help you in that room since it requires permission. I'm in "Android Assistance" if you need me, where I can type freely.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable inside the method, an external method is surely not able to see it, it's not in the same scope, you can still declare it outside and then set a value from inside the `onClick()` method.

Comment: Isn't that what I did?  I have int setHoles; at the very top just under public class EntryScreen ... Then in the on click I set it to 18 or 9, and then use the value in the getHoles

Comment: You got me confused, first you said that when its declared outside its OK, so what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting `EntryScreen.this.setHoles = ...`? Works fine for me

Comment: @MByD - If I say at the beginning of the class, int setHoles = 30; and then i run public int getHoles() {
    return setHoles;
} it returns 30... however, if i do int setHoles; and then i determine what setHoles equals in the "onClick" then when i run getHoles, it returns 0

Comment: @Espiandev - i tried if (items[item].equals("9")){
                  EntryScreen.this.setHoles = 9;
                 } in the onClick but it still returns a 0 outside of the onClick, or outside of the scope... im still a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as `public/private` variable outside the methods.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your setHoles is even being set? to 9 or 18? try adding a println(setHoles) in your onclick to ensure that the value is being set properly. Also, you are declaring your setHoles variable outside of onCreate but within the same class as getHoles() and onClick() right?

Answer (score 0):

when you compare `Strings` always use `equal` method.
like:

```
  if (items[item].equals( "9")){
}
```

and i prefer to user `Setters` and `Getters` on variables:

```
setHoles(int value){}
```

and

`int getHoles(){}`

Comment: Thanks, I updated how I did that but makes no difference in getting the value :(